# Border and Padding width javascript

Tags: javascript, width, border, padding

**UPDATE: Edited javascript code. It's only slightly off now in some columns. Maybe a pixel or two. Not sure why.**

I need to get the border and internal padding width of a cell of a table. I plan to subtract these values from the offsetWidth to get the content width, and use that to set the style.width of another cell. Unfortunately, I can't find a tried-and-true way to get the border and padding width. Anyone got an idea?

UPDATE: I added the code below to show my implementation. It still doesn't align correctly. 
I'm attempting to sync up column widths of the two tables; however, the table widths are setting smaller than the length of all the columns, pushing some columns to not line up.
The table widths are setting too small. :(

```
/*
Utilities.js
Author: Steven T. Norris     Created: 3/2/2012
Updated By:                  Last Updated:
Copyright 2012

Utility functions
Logs to debug window if using Debug.aspx or a logger named 'debug' with the HtmlLoggerControlInstance
*/

/*
Syncs column sizes between two tables. 

@param string table1 : First table to sync
@param int table1HeadRow : Row to use as column width sync for table1 (if null, uses first row)
@param string table2 : Second table to sync
@param int table2HeadRow : Row to use as column width sync for table2 (if null, uses first row)
*/
function syncColumnWidths(table1, table1HeadRow, table2, table2HeadRow) {
    var tableTotal = 0;
    var tableAdd = 0;
    var t1width = 0;
    var t2width = 0;
    var t1Cell;
    var t2Cell;
    var t1CellWidth;
    var t2CellWidth;
    UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.INFO,"-Syncing Column Widths-")
    if((typeof table1 == "string" ||table1.constructor == String) && (typeof table2 == "string" ||table2.constructor == String)
        && (typeof table1HeadRow == "number" || table1HeadRow == null) && (typeof table2HeadRow == "number" || table1HeadRow == null)){
        tableOne = document.getElementById(table1);
        tableTwo = document.getElementById(table2);

        //Set row to check and get row
        if(table1HeadRow == null){
            t1Start = 0;
        }
        else{
            t1Start = table1HeadRow;
        }
        if(table2HeadRow == null){
            t2Start = 0;
        }
        else{
            t2Start = table2HeadRow;
        }
        t1Row = tableOne.rows[t1Start];
        t2Row = tableTwo.rows[t2Start];

        //Get end number
        if(t1Row.cells.length < t2Row.cells.length){
            tEnd = t1Row.cells.length;
        }
        else{
            tEnd = t2Row.cells.length;
        }


        //Sync widths
        for (i = 0; i < tEnd; i++) {
            t1Cell = $("#" + table1+" tr:eq("+t1Start+") td:eq("+i+")");
            t1width = t1Cell.width() + parseInt(t1Cell.css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt(t1Cell.css("padding-right"), 10)
                      + parseInt(t1Cell.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt(t1Cell.css("borderRightWidth"), 10) ;
            t1CellWidth = t1Cell.width();
            t2Cell = $("#" + table2 + " tr:eq(" + t1Start + ") td:eq(" + i + ")");
            t2width = t2Cell.width() + parseInt(t2Cell.css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt(t2Cell.css("padding-right"), 10)
                      + parseInt(t2Cell.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt(t2Cell.css("borderRightWidth"), 10);
            t2CellWidth = t2Cell.width();
            UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.CONFIG, "syncColumnWidths:t1 width:" + t1CellWidth + "   t2 width:" + t2CellWidth);
            if (t1CellWidth > t2CellWidth) {
                tableAdd = t1width;
                t2Row.cells[i].style.width = t1CellWidth + "px";
                t1Row.cells[i].style.width = t1CellWidth + "px";
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE,"syncColumnWidths:setting t2 width to t1");
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER, "syncColumnwidths:t1 style width:" + t1Row.cells[i].style.width + "    t2 style width:" + t2Row.cells[i].style.width);

            }
            else {
                tableAdd = t2width;
                t1Row.cells[i].style.width = t2CellWidth + "px";
                t2Row.cells[i].style.width = t2CellWidth + "px";
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE,"syncColumnWidths:setting t1 width to t2");
                UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER,"syncColumnwidths:t1 style width:"+t1Row.cells[i].style.width+"    t2 style width:"+t2Row.cells[i].style.width);

            }
            tableTotal = tableTotal + tableAdd;
        }
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINE, "setting main table width to " + tableTotal);
        tableOne.style.width = tableTotal + "px"
        tableTwo.style.width = tableTotal + "px"
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER, "tableOne width: " + tableOne.style.width);
        UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.FINER, "tableTwo width: " + tableTwo.style.width);

    }
    else{
        alert("syncColumnWidths takes parameters (string, int|null, string, int|null)");
    }
    UtilLogger.log(HtmlLogger.INFO,"-Syncing Column Widths Complete-");
}
```

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville everything that you do in jQuery can be done in pure javascript

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I am open to using whatever gets the job done. Although javascript can do whatever jQuery can do, seeing as it is javascript itself, jQuery often does it with less hassle and more fun. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var theDiv = $("#theDiv");
var totalWidth = theDiv.width();
totalWidth += parseInt(theDiv.css("padding-left"), 10) + parseInt(theDiv.css("padding-right"), 10); //Total Padding Width
totalWidth += parseInt(theDiv.css("margin-left"), 10) + parseInt(theDiv.css("margin-right"), 10); //Total Margin Width
totalWidth += parseInt(theDiv.css("borderLeftWidth"), 10) + parseInt(theDiv.css("borderRightWidth"), 10); //Total Border Width
```

Borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/349719/339852).

Comment: same question as for Nicola, will this work if the CSS is external or there is no CSS at all?

Comment: Thanks. I'll test for my purposes and see what comes up.

Comment: No go. Still having some sizing issues. I've added my code above for implementation reference.

Comment: It's only a tick off at this point, so I believe it's jsut a margin or something that needs slight adjusting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="my" style="padding: 5px; border:3px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you can do

```
 var padding = document.getElementById('my').style.padding;
 var border = document.getElementById('my').style.border;
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7TmXm/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/349395/339852 As you can see jQuery will do a lot of the work for you in this case.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti What if there is no inline style defined? Say external CSS or no CSS at all. Will this still get the correct values?

Comment: @steventnorris in thatcase, as youare open to jQuery, use jQuery `$('#my').css('padding-left')` will do the trick

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I still seem to have a width problem. I've added my code above for refrence.